# Solution of Diophantine Equation $1+a^6=x^2$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Does the equation $1+a^6=x^2$ have any other integer solutions except the trivial one $a=0,x=1$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's $$(x-a^3)(x+a^3)=1$$ and solve two systems:
$$x-a^3=1$$ and $$x+a^3=1$$ or
$$x-a^3=-1$$ and $$x+a^3=-1,$$
which gives the answer for $(x,a)$:
$$\{(1,0), (-1,0)\}.$$

Answer (score 6):

$x^2$ and $a^6$ are both perfect squares. And the only two perfect squares that differ by $1$ are $0$ and $1$ (because for any $n\ge 0$, the next biggest square after $n^2$ is $n^2+2n+1$).